# ASP.NET Loading a User Control in a Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a Repeater control that loads instances of a custom control I have built. This repeater looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" OnLoad="myRepeater_Load">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  </HeaderTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr><td><my:CustomControl ID="myControl" runat="server" 
      OnLoad="myControl_Load" />
    </td></tr>
  </ItemTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I bind to the Repeater through the `myRepeater_Load` event handler. My custom control is used to render an item within the Repeater. Because of this, I am trying to set properties on the custom control during the `myControl_Load` event handler. However, I do not know how to access the current item during the `myControl_Load` event.

Is there a way I can pass along the current item or access the current item during the `myControl_Load` event? If so, how?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrDemo" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrDemo_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <demo:Sample runat="server" ID="sampleControl" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


protected void rptrDemo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
    {
        SampleControl sampleControl = (SampleControl)e.Item.FindControl("sampleControl");
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the repeater's OnItemDatabound event.

Comment: But how do I access my custom control from the OnItemDataBound event then?

Comment: The event args object will allow you access to your control via e.Item.FindControl() - but you'll have to cast it.  Personally I despise OnItemDataBound and avoid it at all costs

Comment: @Eric, what would you recommend instead?  I would like to know the alternative.  Thanks

Comment: @goku_da_master The alternative is simply to do whatever data binding is necessary in the ASPX/ASCX markup itself (declaratively)

Answer (score 0):

use the OnItemDatabound event of the Repeater

```
        void r_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CustomControl ctl = (CutonControl)e.Item.FindControl("myControl");
        }
    }
```