# How to provide 'data' to User Control inside repeater?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

Can somebody explain the easiest way to provide data to a **user** control inside a repeater?

I have the following:

## Default.aspx

```
<!-- this.GetData() returns IEnumerable<Object> -->
<asp:Repeater runat="server" datasource='<%#this.GetData()%>'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <my:CustomControl runat="server" datasource='<%#Container.DataItem %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Codebehind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBind();
    }
```

## CustomControl.ascx

```
<!-- Object has property Title -->
<h1><%#this.DataSource.Title%></h1>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("DataSource")]
public partial class CustomControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Item DataSource { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = this.DataSource; //null here
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = this.DataSource; //still null
    }
}
```

Comment: is `this.GetData()` getting called before or after `Page_Load` where your databinding is happening. Can you just move `.GetData()` to just before your databinding in `Page_Load`?

Comment: this.GetData() is called with the databinding expression `#`. So it is called ON databinding...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add properties to the user control then set these during the databind.

like this:

```
<!-- this.GetData() returns IEnumerable<Object> -->
<asp:Repeater runat="server" datasource='<%#this.GetData()%>'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <my:CustomControl runat="server" title='<%#Container.DataItem.title %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DataBind();
}
```

CustomControl.ascx

```
<!-- Object has property Title -->
<h1><%#this.Title%></h1>
```

Codebehind:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("DataSource")]
public partial class CustomControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Item DataSource { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = this.DataSource; //null here
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = this.DataSource; //still null
     }
}
```

Comment: The above is slightly different as it doesn't depend on databinding within the usercontrol, only on the page databind. I have in the past that a page.databind didn't propagate to the usercontrol. I can't say for sure, but I'm pretty certain that's the case.

Answer (score -1):

I found an elegant solution on a different post here:
[ASP.NET Loading a User Control in a Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496856/asp-net-loading-a-user-control-in-a-repeater/2496949#2496949) by Anthony Pegram

Summary:

Using the repeater's ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) event to push info into the Web User Control's properties (that you created).